# Combing two lists from regex using Python

Tags: python, string, tuples

I am using regular expression to grab values from a log file using python. The code is as follows:

```
with open(logFile, 'r') as logfile_read:
    for line in logfile_read:
        line = line.rstrip()
            if 'Time' in line:
            iteration_time = re.findall(r'^Time = ([0-9]+)', line)

            if 'cumulative' in line:
                contCumulative_0 = re.search(r'cumulative = (-?[\d|.]+)', line)
               if contCumulative_0:     
                  cumvalue = contCumulative_0.groups(1)
               merge = zip(iteration_time, cumvalue)
               print merge
```

The output with the above code is:

```
[('1', '0.00142109')]
[('2', '0.00354587')]
[('3', '0.00166678')]
[('4', '-0.00477095')]
[('5', '-0.00814067')]
[('6', '-0.00854863')]
[('7', '-0.00710546')]
[('8', '-0.00715775')]
[('9', '-0.00580527')]
[('10', '-0.0061622')]
```

I would like the output to be as below so that I can write to a file and plot it.

```
1   0.00142109
2   0.00354587
3   0.00166678
```

and so on. I am struggling converting the above tuple to strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extra for loop.

```
>>> l = [('1', '0.00142109')]
>>> for (x,y) in l:
...     print(x,y)
... 
1 0.00142109
```

OR

```
>>> for (x,y) in l:
...     print(x+"\t"+y)
... 
1   0.00142109
```

Answer (score 1):

use join and map as below:

```
merge = ' '.join(map(double,merge[0]))
```

as you are writing to file, converting to double is optional:

```
merge = ' '.join(merge[0])
```

Comment: Thanks @user3 merge is able to concatenate the tuples into string as desired.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use Python's `.join()` function to join a list/tuple of strings. For example:

```
>>> tup = ('1', '0.00142109')
>>> print '\t'.join(tup)
1   0.00142109
```